# Variable amount of nested for loops

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, combinatorics

**Edit: I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention that I'll need the values of the counter variables. So making one loop isn't a solution I'm afraid.**

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but I would like to do the following.
To a function, an array of numbers is passed. Each number is the upper limit of a for loop, for example, if the array is `[2, 3, 5]`, the following code should be executed:

```
for(var a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
     for(var b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
          for(var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                doSomething([a, b, c]);
          }
     }
}
```

So the amount of nested for loops is equal to the length of the array. Would there be any way to make this work? I was thinking of creating a piece of code which adds each for loop to a string, and then evaluates it through `eval`. I've read however that `eval` should not be one's first choice as it can have dangerous results too.

What technique might be appropriate here?

Comment: So you just want to call some function a number of times which is equal to the product of the numbers in a passed-in array?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'll need the variables of the for loops (a, b and c here) as well.

Comment: See a more general problem with more simple, modern  and elegant solutions at [this question/solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54506376/287948)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Recursion can solve this problem neatly:

```
function callManyTimes(maxIndices, func) {
    doCallManyTimes(maxIndices, func, [], 0);
}

function doCallManyTimes(maxIndices, func, args, index) {
    if (maxIndices.length == 0) {
        func(args);
    } else {
        var rest = maxIndices.slice(1);
        for (args[index] = 0; args[index] < maxIndices[0]; ++args[index]) {
            doCallManyTimes(rest, func, args, index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
callManyTimes([2,3,5], doSomething);
```

Comment: Your solution also works like a charm. Actually yours is the cleanest one, and easier to understand for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great solution, yours is also the fastest one proposed. My (unscientific) testing shows that if we take native nested loop as a benchmark `X`, then: Sean: `4X`, Guffa: `8X`, Mike Samuel: `15X`, Pointy: `28X`.

Comment: @Sean your recursion works flawlessly, thank you for it. For the last 2 days I've been unsuccessfully trying to recode it to be able to start from given indexes (`args` in your function). For example I would like `callManyTimes([5,5,5], doSomething);` not starting from `[0,0,0]`, but starting from `[2, 4, 5] `. Can someone help me achieve this using @Sean 's code?

Comment: @Reath It's pretty easy to add a `minIndices` parameter: https://pastebin.com/rxswG7bj

Answer (score 10):

Recursion is overkill here.  You can use generators:

```js
function* allPossibleCombinations(lengths) {
  const n = lengths.length;

  let indices = [];
  for (let i = n; --i >= 0;) {
    if (lengths[i] === 0) { return; }
    if (lengths[i] !== (lengths[i] & 0x7fffffff)) { throw new Error(); }
    indices[i] = 0;
  }

  while (true) {
    yield indices;
    // Increment indices.
    ++indices[n - 1];
    for (let j = n; --j >= 0 && indices[j] === lengths[j];) {
      if (j === 0) { return; }
      indices[j] = 0;
      ++indices[j - 1];
    }
  }
}

for ([a, b, c] of allPossibleCombinations([3, 2, 2])) {
  console.log(`${a}, ${b}, ${c}`);
}
```

The intuition here is that we keep a list of indices that are always less than the corresponding length.

The second loop handles carry.  As when incrementing a decimal number 199, we go to (1, 9, 10), and then carry to get (1, 10, 0) and finally (2, 0, 0).  If we don't have enough digits to carry into, we're done.

Comment: That's a ingenious way, too. Could you possibly explain though what you're doing with 0x7fffffff?

Comment: @pimvdb, ensuring that the lengths are non-negative integers so that the `indices[j] === lengths[j]` check below has a chance of passing.

Comment: I saw some ways to condense this and make it more versatile for my use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753698/552067 Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 4):

Set up an array of counters with the same length as the limit array. Use a single loop, and increment the last item in each iteration. When it reaches it's limit you restart it and increment the next item.

```
function loop(limits) {
  var cnt = new Array(limits.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt.length; i++) cnt[i] = 0;
  var pos;
  do {
    doSomething(cnt);
    pos = cnt.length - 1;
    cnt[pos]++;
    while (pos >= 0 && cnt[pos] >= limits[pos]) {
      cnt[pos] = 0;
      pos--;
      if (pos >= 0) cnt[pos]++;
    }
  } while (pos >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking in terms of nested `for` loops, think about recursive function invocations. To do your iteration, you'd make the following decision (pseudo code):

```
if the list of counters is empty
    then "doSomething()"
else
    for (counter = 0 to first counter limit in the list)
        recurse with the tail of the list
```

That might look something like this:

```
function forEachCounter(counters, fn) {
  function impl(counters, curCount) {
    if (counters.length === 0)
      fn(curCount);
    else {
      var limit = counters[0];
      curCount.push(0);
      for (var i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        curCount[curCount.length - 1] = i;
        impl(counters.slice(1), curCount);
      }
      curCount.length--;
    }
  }
  impl(counters, []);
}
```

You'd call the function with an argument that's your list of count limits, and an argument that's your function to execute for each effective count array (the "doSomething" part).  The main function above does all the real work in an inner function. In that inner function, the first argument is the counter limit list, which will be "whittled down" as the function is called recursively. The second argument is used to hold the current set of counter values, so that "doSomething" can know that it's on an iteration corresponding to a particular list of actual counts.

Calling the function would look like this:

```
forEachCounter([4, 2, 5], function(c) { /* something */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution that works without getting complicated programatically would be to take the integers and multiply them all.  Since you're only nesting the ifs, and only the innermost one has functionality, this should work:

```
var product = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    product *= array[i];
}

for(var i = 0; i < product; i++){
    doSomething();
}
```

Alternatively:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < array[i]; j++){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt at simplifying the non-recursive [solution by Mike Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4694438/552067). I also add the ability to set a range (not just maximum) for every integer argument.

```js
function everyPermutation(args, fn) {
    var indices = args.map(a => a.min);

    for (var j = args.length; j >= 0;) {
        fn.apply(null, indices);

        // go through indices from right to left setting them to 0
        for (j = args.length; j--;) {
            // until we find the last index not at max which we increment
            if (indices[j] < args[j].max) {
                ++indices[j];
                break;
            }
            indices[j] = args[j].min;
        }
    }
}

everyPermutation([
    {min:4, max:6},
    {min:2, max:3},
    {min:0, max:1}
], function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a + ',' + b + ',' + c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between doing three loops of 2, 3, 5, and one loop of 30 (2*3*5).

```
function doLots (howMany, what) {
    var amount = 0;

    // Aggregate amount
    for (var i=0; i<howMany.length;i++) {
        amount *= howMany[i];
    };

    // Execute that many times.    
    while(i--) {
        what();
    };
}
```

Use:

```
doLots([2,3,5], doSomething);
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm going to need the values of the counter variables too. Although I love your solution, that information get lost.

Comment: You beat me to it.  Also, what kind of information do you need it for?  Can you simply hold all of the integers in the original array you have?  Or do you need to have them held in some different way?

Comment: I'm trying to create a generic multidimensional array function, so I'll need to fill up each combination of indexes with a value. Hence the nested for loops. One for loop makes the indexes get lost and just returns one index (0 - 30 here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the greedy algorithm to enumerate all elements of the cartesian product 0:2 x 0:3 x 0:5. This algorithm is performed by my function `greedy_backward` below. I am not an expert in Javascript and maybe this function could be improved.

```
function greedy_backward(sizes, n) {
  for (var G = [1], i = 0; i<sizes.length; i++) G[i+1] = G[i] * sizes[i]; 
  if (n>=_.last(G)) throw new Error("n must be <" + _.last(G));
  for (i = 0; i<sizes.length; i++) if (sizes[i]!=parseInt(sizes[i]) || sizes[i]<1){  throw new Error("sizes must be a vector of integers be >1"); }; 
  for (var epsilon=[], i=0; i < sizes.length; i++) epsilon[i]=0;
  while(n > 0){
    var k = _.findIndex(G, function(x){ return n < x; }) - 1;
    var e = (n/G[k])>>0;
    epsilon[k] = e;
    n = n-e*G[k];
  }
  return epsilon;
}
```

It enumerates the elements of the Cartesian product in the anti-lexicographic order (you will see the full enumeration in the `doSomething` example):

```
~ var sizes = [2, 3, 5];
~ greedy_backward(sizes,0);
0,0,0
~ greedy_backward(sizes,1);
1,0,0
~ greedy_backward(sizes,2);
0,1,0
~ greedy_backward(sizes,3);
1,1,0
~ greedy_backward(sizes,4);
0,2,0
~ greedy_backward(sizes,5);
1,2,0
```

This is a generalization of the binary representation (the case when `sizes=[2,2,2,...]`).

Example:

```
~ function doSomething(v){
    for (var message = v[0], i = 1; i<v.length; i++) message = message + '-' + v[i].toString(); 
    console.log(message); 
  }
~ doSomething(["a","b","c"])
a-b-c
~ for (var max = [1], i = 0; i<sizes.length; i++) max = max * sizes[i]; 
30
~ for(i=0; i<max; i++){
    doSomething(greedy_backward(sizes,i));
  }
0-0-0
1-0-0
0-1-0
1-1-0
0-2-0
1-2-0
0-0-1
1-0-1
0-1-1
1-1-1
0-2-1
1-2-1
0-0-2
1-0-2
0-1-2
1-1-2
0-2-2
1-2-2
0-0-3
1-0-3
0-1-3
1-1-3
0-2-3
1-2-3
0-0-4
1-0-4
0-1-4
1-1-4
0-2-4
1-2-4
```

If needed, the reverse operation is simple:

```
function greedy_forward(sizes, epsilon) {
  if (sizes.length!=epsilon.length) throw new Error("sizes and epsilon must have the same length");
  for (i = 0; i<sizes.length; i++) if (epsilon[i] <0 || epsilon[i] >= sizes[i]){  throw new Error("condition `0 <= epsilon[i] < sizes[i]` not fulfilled for all i"); }; 
  for (var G = [1], i = 0; i<sizes.length-1; i++) G[i+1] = G[i] * sizes[i]; 
  for (var n = 0, i = 0; i<sizes.length; i++)  n += G[i] * epsilon[i]; 
  return n;
}
```

Example :

```
~ epsilon = greedy_backward(sizes, 29)
1,2,4
~ greedy_forward(sizes, epsilon)
29
```

Answer (score 0):

One could also use a generator for that:

```
  function loop(...times) {
    function* looper(times, prev = []) {
       if(!times.length) {
           yield prev;
           return;
       }
       const [max, ...rest] = times;
       for(let current = 0; current < max; current++) {
         yield* looper(rest, [...prev, current]);
       }
   }
   return looper(times);
 }
```

That can then be used as:

```
  for(const [j, k, l, m] of loop(1, 2, 3, 4)) {
     //...
  }
```