# Undetermined number of for loops depending on one parameter

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops

I am trying to do the following: A function receives two numbers n and d where n is the number of loops iterations and d is a parameter which determines the loop limits in a way that that something is done to an array of numbers [a_1,...,a_n] for all positive a_1,...,a_n such that they sum up to d. For example, if n=4 it should do something like:

```
for i in range (0,d+1):
    for j in range(0,d+1-i):
        for k in range(0,d+1-i-j):
            doSomething([i, j, k, d-i-j-k])
```

I gather from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683539/variable-amount-of-nested-for-loops) and from my knowledge in programming a few years back that this should be done with a recursive function. Unfortunately I do not quite manage to figure out how I should be passing out parameters (I haven't programmed in a few years, I'm a bit rusty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
def drill(f, n, d, items=()):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(d+1):
            drill(f, n-1, d-i, items+(i,))
    else:
        f(list(items) + [d])
```

... called like this:

```
>>> def p(x): print x
...
>>> drill(p, 3, 4)
[0, 0, 4]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 4, 0]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 0]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 0]
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 1, 0]
[4, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I like this idea. It is simpler than I expected (advantages of Python against C, I suppose). But for some weird reason when I run it in idle I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for the print part

Comment: Ah, then you're using Python 2.x (in which `print` is a statement rather than a function) ... one moment ...

Comment: ... fixed for Python 2.x now.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I thought I was using 3. Maybe I should use 3.

Comment: Python 2 is [supported until 2020](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#update) (and there are still some third-party libraries yet to be ported to Python 3), but Python 3 lets you write nicer code IMO - `print` as a function being a case in point.

Comment: If you are just starting, then there is a good point in using python 3 wherever possible and not depend on those old libs that come for python 2 only.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly use recursion, but you could also just use itertools (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

def call_on_sum_permutations(callable, n, d):
    for a in itertools.product(range(d+1),repeat=n):
        if sum(a) == d:
            callable(a)

def pr(x):
    print(x)

call_on_sum_permutations(pr, 3, 10)
```

This could get unwieldy with large n

(Also note that your description says positive a_1 to a_n, but your code allowed zeros, so I did that too. You might also find it worthwhile to look at itertools.permutations, itertools.combinations and others in that module)

Comment: Thanks. I thought of doing something like this (in fact it is what I have implemented so far, maybe I should have mentioned it) but then I would iterate many times through instances that do not need to be called (i.e. when sum(a)!=n). On the other hand, if I used recursion, I would have the added inefficiency of creating several stacks.

In your opinion, what would be more efficient?

Comment: The recursion will be significantly more efficient when n is large for the reason you state. Otherwise, it probably doesn't make much difference, especially if doSomething is a sufficiently large task.

Comment: Thanks! I intend to have n to be long, so I think I'll go for recursion.